# Sampling quantities with a fixed sum ("string cutting"), but those quantities have to be discrete

Tags: sampling, dirichlet-distribution

I would like to sample 6 quantities that are guaranteed to add up to 600, each with a mean of 100. I want to be control the amount of variance around 100 (same variance for all 6 quantities, but need ability to crank up/down), so the multinomial distribution won't do (can only specify probability). I can kind of do so with the Dirichlet distribution (R code below):

```
library(MCMCprecision)
sims <- 
  rdirichlet(1e5, a=rep(100,6))*600
```

However, there is an issue. I want those quantities to be discrete (rounded to the nearest number), not continuous. If I round them, sometimes the sum adds up to something other than 600 (e.g., 599 or 601).

Is there a way to achieve something similar, but only sample discrete numbers, rather than the whole line? I was thinking of something like how the geometric distribution is a discrete counterpart to the exponential, but not sure if there is any equivalent thing here.

One thing I thought of was to just filter and only keep the samples that sum to 600:

```
sims <- 
  round(rdirichlet(1e5, a=rep(100,6))*600)
hist(sims[rowSums(sims)==600,])
```

But not sure if that somehow biases things. Visually it looks similar to the unfiltered distribution.

Comment: Interesting question. This is related to the [stars and bars technique in combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)): you want to randomly place 5 bars among 600 stars, with prespecified expectation and variance on the bin contents. In the end, it comes down to specifying an appropriate PMF on a discrete distribution with ${605 \choose 5}$ possible outcomes.

Comment: Within rather broad limits, employing a Dirichlet distribution and discretizing its results ought to be an excellent approximation to what you seek.  This will break down only when the variances are less than about $10$ (corresponding to single-digit variation in the values).

Comment: Ok, both makes sense, thanks! I will stick with the discretized Dirichlet approach, filtering out the cases where the discretized sum is not 600.